# json decode certain duplicated value with php

Tags: php, json, decode

Here's the link i want to decode:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/28855276/media/recent/?client_id=775829274b6f48c1ac2bf218dda60e16

Actually i've tried many methods to get the result i want but i failed to do so with PHP.

i need to extract a value from this json which should equal a certain variable
Example:
$variable = json_value

The Hard thing here that i want a duplicated value.
the value i need is:

```
profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_28855276_75sq_1348344197.jpg"
```

Do not know how to reach this value.

Here's it's place in the json file

```
{"username":"zedd","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_28855276_75sq_1348344197.jpg","id":"28855276","full_name":"Zedd"}
```

Please note that i've the username and id values already known.
Need to extract the profile_picture link to a PHP variable.

Please note: profile_picture is duplicated.

Comment: Are you aware of [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)? After that it's just an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

There is no duplication by me.

```
<?php

$array  = json_decode('{"username":"zedd","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_28855276_75sq_1348344197.jpg","id":"28855276","full_name":"Zedd"}',true);

echo $array['profile_picture'];

?>
```